# Hibernate error： java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

i am a beginner.when i use hibernate in eclipse,it shows :

> ERROR: Access denied for user 'root           '@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection

i am a beginner.please help me,i don't konw what's wrong,and i counld not find a suitable answer throught the Internet or other answers on the stack overflow for my project.

Screenshot:

[image]

here is my code:

hibernate.properties:

```
 hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_test

    hibernate.connection.username = root            

    hibernate.connection.password = root

    hibernate.show_sql=true

    hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- 映射文件  -->
        <mapping resource="product/Product.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Product.java:

```
package product;

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private String factory;
    private String remark;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }
    public void setFactory(String factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }
    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }



}
```

Product.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="product.Product" table="product">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string" length="16">
            <column name="name"/>
        </property>

        <property name="price" type="double">
            <column name="price"/>
        </property>

        <property name="factory" type="string" length="25">
            <column name="factory"/>
        </property>

        <property name="remark" type="string" length="60">
            <column name="remark"/>
        </property>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

HibernateUtil.java:

```
package com.wgh.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;



public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal <Session>(); 
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;        //SessionFactory对象
//静态块
static {
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();        //加载Hibernate配置文件
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().buildServiceRegistry());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("创建会话工厂失败");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * 获取Session
     *  @return Session
     *  @throws HibernateException
     */
    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession(): null;
            threadLocal.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }
    /**
     * 重建会话工厂
     */
    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();        //加载Hibernate配置文件
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().buildServiceRegistry());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("创建会话工厂失败");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * 获取SessionFactory对象
     * @return SessionFactory对象
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    /** 
     * 关闭Session
     *  @throws HibernateException
     */
    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        threadLocal.set(null);
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();                            //关闭Session
        }
    }
}
```

servlet:  QueryEmployee.java:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import product.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.wgh.hibernate.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class QueryEmployee
 */
@WebServlet("/QueryEmployee")
public class QueryEmployee extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public QueryEmployee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        List<Product> product_list = new ArrayList<Product>();//实例化List信息集合
        Session session = null;// 实例化session对象

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();// 获得session对象
            String hql = "from Product";// 查询HQL语句
            Query q = session.createQuery(hql);// 执行查询操作
            product_list = q.list();//将返回的对象转化为List集合
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();// 关闭session
        }

        request.setAttribute("product_list", product_list);
        RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);


    }

}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-left:5px solid #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    font: normal 12px/ 17px Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
th {
    font: bold 12px/ 17px Arial;
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#main{
    width:500px;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
}
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="main">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="30px">编号</th>
        <th width="30px">书名</th>
        <th width="30px" align="center">价格</th>
        <th width="80px">生产商</th>
        <th width="135px">备注</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${product_list}" var="list">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">${list.id}</td>
            <td>${list.name}</td>
            <td>${list.price}</td>
            <td>${list.factory}</td>
            <td>${list.remark}</td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<form action="QueryEmployee" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="查看" >
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the whole error message:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1711)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at servlet.QueryEmployee.doPost(QueryEmployee.java:59)
    at servlet.QueryEmployee.doGet(QueryEmployee.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root          '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1717)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 46 more
九月 16, 2017 9:24:26 上午 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
九月 16, 2017 9:24:26 上午 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root         '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1711)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at servlet.QueryEmployee.doPost(QueryEmployee.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root          '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1717)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 45 more
九月 16, 2017 9:27:26 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
信息: Reloading Context with name [/my_hibernate] has started
九月 16, 2017 9:27:26 上午 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
警告: The web application [my_hibernate] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
九月 16, 2017 9:27:27 上午 org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
信息: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
九月 16, 2017 9:27:27 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
信息: Reloading Context with name [/my_hibernate] is completed
```

Comment: What is database password

Answer (score 0):

You don't have mysql server running or your mysql server does not have username=root or password=root, or you do not have access from the host that hibernate is running.

Check your mysql server's user accounts for 'root'.

Comment: thank you.I create a new web project,and copy the code to the new project,finally restart eclipse and tomcat.as a result,It work.